# How/Can I call FASTAPI async function within a stripe webhook handler or is my approach completely wrong?

Tags: python, rest, stripe-payments, fastapi, tortoise-orm

from a high level I am trying to implement a stripe webhook and I want to handle a successful event by updating a value in my database to true. The approach I took was to create an async function called `handle_verification` which gets the current logged-in user and updates the id_verified flag.

```py
@app.get("/user")
async def get_current_user(authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    authorize.jwt_required()
    id = authorize.get_jwt_subject()
    return await User_Pydantic.from_queryset_single(UserModel.get(id=id))

@app.put('/user/verify')
async def handle_verification():
    user = await get_current_user()
    await UserModel.filter(id=user.id).update(id_verified = True)
```

I try to call this function in the webhook code here

```py
@app.post('/create-verification-session')
async def create_verification_session(request: Request):
    verification_session = stripe.identity.VerificationSession.create(
        type='document',
    )
    return verification_session.client_secret

@app.post('/verification-session-webhook')
async def webhook(request: Request ):
    webhook_secret = os.getenv('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET')
    data = await request.body()
    print(data)
    signature = request.headers.get('stripe-signature')
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload=data,
            sig_header=signature,
            secret=webhook_secret
        )
        event_data = event['data']['object']
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        print(str(e))
        return {'error': str(e)}
    event_type = event['type']
    
    if event_type == 'identity.verification_session.created':
        print("Started verification")

        print(event_data.url)
    if event_type == 'identity.verification_session.verified':
        print("All the verification checks passed")
        await handle_verification()
    return {'status': "success"}
```

and I get the error

`AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'jwt_required`

I know this error comes from `get_current_user()` as something is messed up with the async order. I've tried putting `handle_verification` into a sync wrapper function that used asyncio.run() and that did not work.

I have tried a variety of different fix attempts and I think the core issue is I am still learning about async and webhooks and all that jazz so I am completely stumped. I would appreciate any help on my approach to this problem and also any insights into a different approach that might be easier than what I have now. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with FastAPI and FastAPI JWT Auth but I'll try to help out.

I reviewed the [FastAPI JWT Auth](https://indominusbyte.github.io/fastapi-jwt-auth/usage/basic/) examples and it seems to me you want to remove the `async` specifier from your `get_current_user()` function.  All the examples I've found make sure that portion of the code is synchronous.  Hopefully that's all it will take to ensure you don't call `.jwt_required()` *before* your `authorize` object is properly instantiated.

Comment: Hi, just tried that approach and I get another error. `ValueError: [TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]` I suspect how Pydantic works is I have to make it async

Comment: I find it interesting that all the FastAPI JWT Auth code examples use sync function definitions while all the examples for FastAPI use async.  A little hard to untangle.